# What is the following Frame called?

Tags: website-design, css, terminology, borders

[image]

I'd like to design something like this with CSS but I need to know the name to google it. I tried to Google similar images to no avail.

Comment: Sorry.. like what? The double rectangles? That's not a simple CSS border. It would take [2 divs](https://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/me2vonLy/10/) (or before:: or after:: elements). It's an art deco border, but I doubt you'll find anything related to CSS for that.

Comment: You mean the two yellow border rectangles?

Comment: @vikas sorry could have been more specific: yes the yellow rectangles

Comment: @Scott  thanks!, that helps already a bit...

Comment: You could also use SVG if you needed more flexibility. You might also be able to create it using special gradients as a `background-image`

Answer (score 2):

The two yellow rectangles make an **Art Deco** style border.

But I doubt that'll be helpful in terms of Cascading Style Sheets (CSS). It's not possible to use the `border` property in CSS to create such a thing.

There may be a few ways in CSS to construct something similar. Just off the top of my head .. using [absolute positioning and 2 divs](https://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/me2vonLy/12/) could work:

```
<div id="A">
<div id="B">
<h1>A bunch of stuff here</h1>
</div>
</div>

#A {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 25px;
  display: block;
  width: 550px;
  height: 450px;
  border: 2px solid #a00;
}

#B {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  left: -25px;
  z-index: 5;
  display: block;
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 2px solid #a00;
  text-align: center;
}
```

[image]

(...or you could use pseudo elements (::before or ::after) to create the second div.)